# Back and Nav Up have different results

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-manifest, android-lifecycle

I'm having an issue with activity navigation and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a `MainActivity` and a `SettingsActivity` but using the `Back` and `Up` (on the action bar) have two different results from the Settings Activity.

For example If I press the Back button I get the following lifecycle callbacks within the `MainActivity`:

```
V/lifeCycle: onOptionsItemSelected
V/lifeCycle: onPause
V/lifeCycle: onSaveInstanceState-Bundle[..]
V/lifeCycle: onStop
<< PRESS BACK BUTTON >>
V/lifeCycle: onRestart
V/lifeCycle: onStart
V/lifeCycle: onResume
V/lifeCycle: onPostResume
```

While if I press the Navigate UP button i get these results:

```
V/lifeCycle: onOptionsItemSelected
V/lifeCycle: onPause
V/lifeCycle: onSaveInstanceState-Bundle[..]
V/lifeCycle: onStop
<< PRESS NAV UP >>
V/lifeCycle: onDestroy // Problem
V/lifeCycle: onCreate  // Seems
V/lifeCycle: onStart   // Here
V/lifeCycle: onResume
V/lifeCycle: onPostResume
```

The issue is when I press the `Nav UP` my Main Activity gets destroyed and recreated meaning I loose all my view states, but pressing the back button does not do this.

I'm not sure if it's how I'm starting the `PreferenceActivity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
```

Or how my intents in `AndroidManifest.xml` are configured:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

That might be causing the issue, or if this is just the correct behaviour that I need to override and if so, what is the "correct" way to override?

Comment: Via G+ I was directed to `NavUtils` and the [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) guide, This was very helpful in my understanding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<s>Remove</s>

> android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"

from your manifest file for *SettingsActivity*.

Edit: Above step no longer necessary.

In your SettingsActivity class, do the following:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return (true);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, `android.R.id.home` was the nugget I was missing to search for. However I left `android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"` in because removing it removed the action bar button all together. but now Back and UP do the same thing.